# how to query for GET /v2/organizations/:guid/managers using cf-python-client module

Tags: python, cloud-foundry, cf-python-client

I am using `cf-python-client` module downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-python-client)  and I am trying to get managers of an organization

I am able to get the organisation information by this
`client.v2.organizations.get(org_guid)` but now I want to get the managers associated with this org and the API required is `GET /v2/organizations/:guid/managers` but i dont know how to use it through `cf-python-client` module.

This is how i am connecting to Cloudfoundry

```
from cloudfoundry_client.client import CloudFoundryClient
client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, proxy=proxy, verify=False)
client.init_with_user_credentials( 'admin', 'password' )
```

i tried this `client.v2.organizations._get("/"+ORG_GUID+"/managers")` and got this 
error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "orgs.py", line 31, in <module>
print client.v2.organizations._get("/"+ORG_GUID+"/managers")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/cloudfoundry_client/v2/entities.py", line 54, in _get
response = self.client.get(url)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/cloudfoundry_client/client.py", line 167, in get
return CloudFoundryClient._check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/cloudfoundry_client/client.py", line 194, in _check_response
raise InvalidStatusCode(response.status_code, body)
cloudfoundry_client.errors.InvalidStatusCode: 404 : {"code": 10000, 
"error_code": "CF-NotFound", "description": "Unknown request"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :)

```
from cloudfoundry_client.client import CloudFoundryClient
import os
target_endpoint = '<API_URL>'
proxy = dict(http=os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY', ''), https=os.environ.get('HTTPS_PROXY', ''))
client = CloudFoundryClient(target_endpoint, proxy=proxy, verify=False)
client.init_with_user_credentials('<EMAIL>', '<PASSWORD>')
org_get = client.v2.organizations.get('<GUID>')
print(org_get)
for m in org_get.managers():
    print(m)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was useful!